# Ansible array in one task

Tags: arrays, ansible, ansible-awx, big-ip

I have a problem with ansible array's.

I have a task like this:

```
  tasks:   
  - name: create member and add to pool 
    bigip_pool_member:
      pool: "{{pool_name}}"
      partition: "{{partition}}"
      host: "{{ip}}"
      name: "{{ip}}"
      port: "{{port}}"
      monitors:
        - "{{item}}"
      loop: "{{monitor}}"
      description: "{{description_member}}" 
      provider:
               ####
```

And I want to add multiple monitors to the pool. Only it does not work. I need to do this in one task. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop will run the task multiple times. It looks like you should be simply giving the array to the task directly:

```
  - name: create member and add to pool 
    bigip_pool_member:
      pool: "{{pool_name}}"
      partition: "{{partition}}"
      host: "{{ip}}"
      name: "{{ip}}"
      port: "{{port}}"
      monitors: "{{monitor}}"
      description: "{{description_member}}"
```